# How do I optimize my code to make my greedy algorithm better?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

An Egyptian fraction was written as a sum of unit fractions, meaning the numerator is always 1; further, no two denominators can be the same. As easy way to create an Egyptian fraction is to repeatedly take the largest unit fraction that will fit, subtract to find what remains, and repeat until the remainder is a unit fraction, for example:

1. 7 divided by 15 is less than 1/2 but more than 1/3, so the first unit 
   fraction is 1/3 and the first remainder is 2/15.
2. Then 2/15 is less than 1/7 but more than 1/8, so the second unit fraction 
   is 1/8 and the second remainder is 1/120.
3. That’s in unit form, so we are finished: 
   7 ÷ 15 = 1/3 + 1/8 + 1/120

I'm trying to solve the egyptian fraction problem where I'm using the below greedy method:

```
   def egyptianFraction(nr, dr): 

    print("The Egyptian Fraction " +
          "Representation of {0}/{1} is". 
                format(nr, dr), end="\n") 

    # empty list ef to store 
    # denominator 
    ef = [] 

    # while loop runs until  
    # fraction becomes 0 i.e, 
    # numerator becomes 0 
    while nr != 0: 

        # taking ceiling 
        x = math.ceil(dr / nr) 

        # storing value in ef list 
        ef.append(x) 

        # updating new nr and dr 
        nr = x * nr - dr 
        dr = dr * x 

    # printing the values 
    for i in range(len(ef)): 
        if i != len(ef) - 1: 
            print(" 1/{0} +" .  
                    format(ef[i]), end = " ") 
        else: 
            print(" 1/{0}" . 
                    format(ef[i]), end = " ") 

# calling the function 
egyptianFraction(6, 14)
```

I need to build an algorithm that guarantees a maximum number of terms or a minimum largest denominator; for instance,

```
5 ÷ 121 = 1/25 + 1/757 + 1/763309 + 1/873960180913 + 
1/1527612795642093418846225

but a simpler rendering of the same number is 
1/33 + 1/121 + 1/363.
```

Comment: sorry if it bothered you, just trying to get some help.

Comment: I think Codereview StackExchange site would be the right place for this kind of questions - provided that you are not posting duplicates of course.

Comment: This is a mathematical question. I have just had a look on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) searching for *egyptian fraction* and found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1728268/210087). It has no answer but a comment gave this useful [link](http://kevingong.com/Math/EgyptianFractions.pdf). But this is link only, hence only a comment...

Comment: The overarching problem is that you *can't* force your greedy algorithm to provide the minimized result.  *Greedy* is too simplistic to realize the properties in prime factorization of the denominator.  You have to release *greedy* and switch to one of the other algorithms -- which are readily available through a browser search.

Comment: I tried searching, but not able to find anything

Comment: Looks like one for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ggdx thank you for the suggestion, that helped